# Is is bad practice to use php to load a separate header for mobile, in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

My questions is just as the title states: Is is bad practice to use php to load a separate header for mobile, in WordPress?

CSS, JS, and PHP can often accomplish similar tasks/requests. Would it be frowned upon to load up a unique header rather than use CSS and JS to reshuffle important page elements?

EDIT: Case/Point: 
WordPress has a built in function wp_is_mobile to check if mobile (I'm not sure how good it is, but for this example let's assume it gets the job done).

I would add to my index.php file the following,

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
   get_header('mobileMcPhoneFace');
} else {
   get_header();
}
?>
```

The separate header would be unique.

Comment: Are you asking for SEO or best practice purposes?

Comment: @Brogan for Best Practice purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want to show specific elemnt only to mobile...
from what it's sound it can end up with seo problem,
search engine will think you might hide something
then again
it's a way you should avoid.
it's better to let css or javascript handle this kind of task

Comment: On second thought, maybe I've been staring at this all day, and I've thought too much inside the box. I want to load up a unique nav/search/social div for mobile, I could just pop that into it's own php file and leave the header to handle the if, without having to reload the ENTIRE thing?

Comment: in my narrow opinion and experience:

Comment: just load the element you want... for a mobile and for big screens and give it a unique html element id (like id = "mobile-nav"). and with css and media query show it only on small screens...

Comment: I like your idea. I have put it into action. It makes much more sense to target the part, and not the whole.